# Calculation to be performed in the on create method of the Main Activity not executed

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the process of learning android development, now I am developing an app for income tax calculation. The java code for the same is as follows. The spinner and TextWatcher in it have no problem. But the calculation to be done for setText of the EditText fields ti, r87, taxA, totTax, ces, balTax etc. are not seen implemented. There is no error in the compilation of the code and the app can be installed on a device. Please let me know what is wrong with my code. I am new to programming hence please suggest tutorials books to learn java coding in android.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] age = {"Below 60", "60 to 80", "Above 80"};
    EditText salary, other, gi,tax1,r87,taxA,totTax,ces,taxPaid,balTax,hra,ti;
    MyTextWatcher tWatcher;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, age);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource((android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item));
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
        salary = findViewById(R.id.salary);
        other = findViewById(R.id.other);
        gi = findViewById(R.id.gi);
        tWatcher = new MyTextWatcher();
        salary.addTextChangedListener(tWatcher);
        other.addTextChangedListener(tWatcher);
        ti=findViewById(R.id.ti);
        tax1 = findViewById(R.id.tax1);
        taxA = findViewById(R.id.taxA);
        r87=findViewById(R.id.r87);
        totTax=findViewById(R.id.totTax);
        ces=findViewById(R.id.ces);
        taxPaid=findViewById(R.id.taxPaid);
        balTax=findViewById(R.id.balTax);
        hra=findViewById(R.id.hra);

        String w = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();


        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(gi.getText().toString().trim())
                || !TextUtils.isEmpty(hra.getText().toString().trim())) {
            int a = TextUtils.isEmpty(gi.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(salary.getText().toString().trim());
            int b = TextUtils.isEmpty(hra.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(other.getText().toString().trim());
            int answer = a - b;
            Log.e("RESULT", String.valueOf(answer));
            ti.setText(String.valueOf(answer));



            double z;
            double rz = 0;
            double tax = 0;
            double rtax;
            double cess;
            double rcess;

            if (w.equals ("Below 60")) {

                z = a - b;
                rz = Math.round(z / 10.0) * 10;
                if (rz <= 500000) {
                    tax = 0;
                } else if (rz <= 1000000) {
                    tax = (0.2 * (rz - 500000)) + 12500;
                } else if (rz > 1000000) {
                    tax = (0.3 * (rz - 1000000)) + 112500;
                }
                double rtax1;
                double relief87;
                if (rz <= 500000 && rz > 250000) {
                    rtax1 = Math.round((rz - 250000) * 5 / 100);
                    relief87 = rtax1;
                } else {
                    rtax1 = Math.round(tax);
                    relief87 = 0;
                }
                tax1.setText(String.valueOf(rtax1));
                r87.setText(String.valueOf(relief87));
            } else if (w.equals("60 to 80")) {

                z = a - b;
                rz = Math.round(z / 10.0) * 10;

                if (rz <= 500000) {
                    tax = 0;
                } else if (rz <= 1000000) {
                    tax = (0.2 * (rz - 500000)) + 10000;
                } else if (rz > 1000000) {
                    tax = (0.3 * (rz - 1000000)) + 110000;
                }
                double rtax1;
                double relief87;
                if (rz <= 500000 && rz > 300000) {
                    rtax1 = Math.round((rz - 300000) * 5 / 100);
                    relief87 = rtax1;
                } else {
                    rtax1 = Math.round(tax);
                    relief87 = 0;
                }
                tax1.setText(String.valueOf(rtax1));
                r87.setText(String.valueOf(relief87));
            } else if (w.equals("Above 80")) {

                z = a - b;
                rz = Math.round(z / 10.0) * 10;
                if (rz <= 500000) {
                    tax = 0;
                }

                if (rz <= 500000) {
                    tax = 0;
                } else if (rz <= 1000000) {
                    tax = (0.2 * (rz - 500000));
                } else if (rz > 1000000) {
                    tax = (0.3 * (rz - 1000000)) + 100000;
                }

                double rtax1;
                double relief87;
                rtax1 = Math.round(tax);
                relief87 = 0;

                tax1.setText(String.valueOf(rtax1));
                r87.setText(String.valueOf(relief87));
            }

            rtax = Math.round(tax);
            cess = rtax * 4 / 100;
            rcess = Math.round(cess);
            double totalTax = rtax + rcess;
            String totTax1 = String.valueOf(totalTax);
            totTax.setText(totTax1);
            String taxinc = String.valueOf(rz);
            ti.setText(taxinc);
            String result = String.valueOf(rtax);
            taxA.setText(result);
            String zess = String.valueOf(rcess);
            ces.setText(zess);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(taxPaid.getText().toString().trim())) {
                int s17 = TextUtils.isEmpty(taxPaid.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(taxPaid.getText().toString().trim());
                int tp = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s17));
                double taxbal = totalTax - tp;
                balTax.setText(String.valueOf(taxbal));


            }

        }

    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(salary.getText().toString().trim())
                            || !TextUtils.isEmpty(other.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        int firstValue = TextUtils.isEmpty(salary.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(salary.getText().toString().trim());
                        int secondValue = TextUtils.isEmpty(other.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(other.getText().toString().trim());

                        int answer = firstValue + secondValue;
                        Log.e("RESULT", String.valueOf(answer));
                        gi.setText(String.valueOf(answer));

                    }else {
                        gi.setText("");
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                }
            }



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), age[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    }
```

Comment: is your `gi` and `hra` EditText have prefilled value or taking input from user? because when activity is open then as per [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)  `onCreate()` method run automatically and that calculation method never run if  `gi` and `hra` EditText are empty.

Comment: Taking input from user. Is there a way to solve the problem. Thank you for the reply

Comment: simply take one `button` when user filled both value `gi` and `hra`  after then user click on `button` so put that calculation on button click. Second approach is that you can use `TextWatcher` in `gi` and `hra` and put calculation in `onTextChanged`

Comment: Put the calculation on button has solved the problem. Thanks.